# Возникает ошибка при сборке простой программы

Tags: makefile, c++

Ситуация: есть программа, которая работает так, как и было задумано, если её скомпилировать вручную. Теперь я добавляю универсальный makefile чтобы автоматизировать процесс сборки. Если верить [этому руководству](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=100976.0), то всё должно собираться простой командой make, если makefile лежит в папке с исходниками (или я что-то неправильно понял).

```
#makefile
TARGET  = $( shell basename `pwd` )
SOURCES = $( wildcard *.cpp ) 
OBJECTS = $( SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o )

all: $(TAGRET)

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)

$(TAGRET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $(TAGRET) $(LDFLAGS) $(OGJECTS) $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(TAGRET)

.PHONY: all clean
```

Но команда `make` даёт вот такой результат:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

а команда `make Greetings` вот такой:

```
g++     Greetings.cpp   -o Greetings
/tmp/cclc1PYt.o: In function `main':
Greetings.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `MyGreetingsPrinter::MyGreetingsPrinter()'
Greetings.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `MyGreetingsPrinter::PrintGreetings()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Greetings] Error 1
```

В чём ошибка?

Comment: B и G на клавиатуре рядом. Вот и появилось новое слово OGJECTS

Comment: Пофиксил ещё ошибку TAGRET - TARGET, но результат тот же. Видимо, почему-то он сначала пытается скомпилить главную функцию, а не класс, который в ней используется.

Comment: Убрал пробелы между скобками и заработало...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В скрипте было несколько орфографических ошибок и недопустимых пробелов между скобками.